# Storing and comparing pairs of integers without arrays or lists

Tags: c#, do-while

I want to ask user for unlimited integers (between `99` and `-99`) then group every number by two, output the biggest pair (I can't use arrays or `List<>`, or `for` loops)

By "biggest pair" I mean e.g when the inputs are: `7; 5; 3; 2; 9;` the biggest pair is `12` i.e. `7 + 5`

I'm struggling to store and compare pairs of sums

```
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int MAX = 99;
            const int MIN = -99;
            int current;
            int prev;
            int sum;
            sum = 0;
            prev = 0;
            current = 0;
            do
            {
                
                current = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (current > MAX)
                {
                    current = 100;
                }
                else if (current < MIN)
                {
                    current = 100;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("___________");
                Console.WriteLine("prev =" + prev);
                sum = prev + current;
                Console.WriteLine("Math.Max prev and sum = " + Math.Max(prev, sum));
                Console.WriteLine("sum = " + sum);
                prev = current;
                Console.WriteLine("prev =" + prev);
                
            }
            while (current != 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Break your problem into steps. First, figure out how to accept _single_ integers and identify the largest without storing them all in an array? Next, figure out how to ask for two integers before you treat their sum as the _single integer_ you were able to process from before.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thank you, managed to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp54
{
    class Program
    {
       

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start:
            const int MAX = 99;
            const int MIN = -99;
            int current;
            int prev;
            int sum;
            int SumMax;
            sum = 0;
            prev = 0;
            current = 0;
            SumMax = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Input integer from -99 to 99");
            do
            {
                
                current = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (current > MAX)
                {
                    
                    current = 100;
                    goto TheEnd;
                }
                else if (current < MIN)
                {
                    
                    current = 100;
                    goto TheEnd;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("___________");
                Console.WriteLine("prev =" + prev);
                sum = prev + current;
                Console.WriteLine("Math.Max prev and sum = " + Math.Max(prev, sum));
                Console.WriteLine("sum = " + sum);
                if (sum>SumMax)
                {
                    SumMax = sum;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("All time Max =" + SumMax);
                prev = current;
                Console.WriteLine("prev =" + prev);

            }
            while (current != 100);
        TheEnd:
            Console.WriteLine("incorrect input try: - 99 до 99! ");
            goto Start;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).